# Development server for version control, wiki, and continuous-integration

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration

I'm familiar with the typical development server stack:

1. SVN
2. Trac
3. Jenkins/Hudson

Now I'm looking for something that can handle distributed version control (I'm leaning towards Mercurial).

Of course, if I can have all the perks of the above stack, that'd be great!

- Platform agnostic (clients run on Windows, Mac, Linux)
- Language/technology agnostic (i.e. Java **and** .NET compilation)
- Server is platform agnostic (CI and Wiki can run on any server)
- IDE integration for the above platforms (Eclipse, Visual Studio, etc.)
- Slices, dices, and makes thousands of julienne fries!

If I should cross-post on StackOverflow, let me know.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) is my preferred FOSS solution.  Tie it all together with a [Hudson to Redmine plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Redmine+Plugin), and [Redmine to Hudson plugin](http://code.google.com/p/r-labs/downloads/list).